# Magento 2 : Where is Estimated Shipping Information Saved

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, shipping-address

**In which session or object, estimated shipping summary from cart is saving ?**

When I checking checkout process, shipping form is pre-filling with that estimated information.

But any idea how we can take these values ?

**[SOLVED]**

I think Got it,

Magento2 saving data in local storage 'mage-cache-storage'.

Not sure, but I can see values there in shippingAddressFromData Object.

Comment: Are you talking about Cart page shipping method?

Comment: Yes,  the cart summary box area

Comment: please let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shipping method value are saved in **localstorage.**
You can find selected shipping rate from localstorage key, **mage-cache-storage** and get value from **selectedShippingRate**

File is responsible for that,

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/shipping-rates.js
```

Here function is called,

```
selectShippingMethod: function (methodData) {
    selectShippingMethodAction(methodData);
    checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(methodData['carrier_code'] + '_' + methodData['method_code']);
    return true;
}
```

Save logic from     **`checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(methodData['carrier_code'] + '_' + methodData['method_code']);`**

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.
Do you think is it possible to change or call these values by custom javascript ?

Comment: @jpk Actually what do you want to do?

Comment: I have some custom shipping rate calculations based on city and zipcode.
So need to set this shipping method and rate only if these inputs are valid.
Right now i have done this calculation in cart page with jQuery and got response.. but i cannot able to set this new  rate and method via javascript from jquery response.

Comment: @jpk,may be This is some complicated task. I think you have to ask new question for this issue with brief. May be someone expert do a help for you.

Comment: @jpk You can close this question so other users have useful in future.

Comment: i cannot see the option to close.

Comment: @jpk you can just accept as solution for answer and your question become close.